# Unable to import mockito imports using testCompile in gradle

Tags: android, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to import mockito in my project and is impossible. I've spend a lot of time trying... I'm using Android Studio 3.0

I have this in gradle dependencies:

```
testCompile  'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile  "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"
testCompile  "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
testCompile  "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
```

But I can't import anything about mockito in my test class.

If I change testCompile to

```
androidTestCompile  'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile  "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"
androidTestCompile  "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
androidTestCompile  "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
```

I can import all, but when I try to run a test I have this error in logcat:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':myproject:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForMyprojectDebugAndroidTest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Some help will be apreciate!

Comment: You've probably hit the dex limit.

Comment: I had tu add     androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'
With this, I can see the imports

Comment: and updating powermock to 1.7.3 version

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using incompatible versions of powermock and mockito.
Based on [compatibility table](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions) powermock-1.6.2 is compatible with Mockito 1.10.x.

Try mockito 2.8.9 and powermock 1.7.3 for example.

Not sure if this is the case but you would stumble into problems anyway later on while running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site ...  http://gradleplease.appspot.com/  and search what library u want

and Must add mavan in build.gradle(Project:xxx)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}